# issues with SPM12 and iMac (Apple M1) - Sonoma

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-spm

I get this error. I've tried to fix it following the guidelines online but it seems impossible to solve.
Can someone help me please?

> Error using spm_check_installation>check_basic
> SPM uses a number of MEX files, which are compiled functions.
> These need to be compiled for the various platforms on which SPM
> is run. It seems that the compiled files for your computer platform
> are missing or not compatible. See
> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPM/Installation_on_64bit_Mac_OS_(Intel)
> for information about how to compile MEX files for MACI64
> in MATLAB 23.2.0.2485118 (R2023b) Update 6.
>
> ```
> Error in spm_check_installation (line 28)
>        check_basic;
>
> Error in spm (line 290)
> spm_check_installation('basic');
> ```

I tried to follow https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPM/Installation_on_64bit_Mac_OS_(Intel)and also this command  `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine *.mexmaci64` suggested by Chris Rorden.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the solution on the SPM installation instructions website, which worked for me:

https://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/docs/installation/#macos

TLDR; in the terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/spm/spm.git
```